# Shiny server.r / ui.r variable isn't being passed

Tags: r, shiny

*edit
Apologies - okay, will edit this rather than the add from now on.

So; thanks for your suggestions, but they just haven't worked for me. As a result, I've gone completely back to basics. Taking the original script from the shiny help site (Section 5, 2nd Answer) and simply pasting my stuff around it:

```
# server.R

setwd("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Shapefiles/ITV Region (Working) - Shiny App/")
require(maptools)
require(ggplot2)
require(RColorBrewer)
require (ggmap)
require (scales)
require (dplyr)
source("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/Shapefiles/poly_coords.r")

## load the shapefile
Shpfile <- readShapePoly("shpfiles/ITVRegion.shp")
names(Shpfile)
names(Shpfile)<- c("ID", "NAME", "Shape_Length", "Shape_Area")
Shpfile_geom <- poly_coords(Shpfile)

mapdata <-  read.table("data/ITVRegionKeyedData_Test.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")
Plotdata <- left_join(Shpfile_geom, mapdata)

print("Build has run successfully")

shinyServer(
function(input, output) {output$map <- renderPlot({

  ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data = Plotdata, aes(y = PolyCoordsX, x = PolyCoordsY, group = Poly_Name, fill = input$metric), color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  coord_map()  ## This maintains shape and avoids distortion
})
}
)
```

Nothing fancy. No switching. No separate reactive instances.
I get an error reporting:   object 'input' not found

If I switch out that input$metric with simply Households  (no quotes) then the map renders my households column in the data. What I just need is for the metric column selected from my UI to be dropped in to the geom_polygon block.

Maybe it's just me not understanding data types, and I need to convert the text from the UI in to a field header?

```
# ui.R

shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("censusVis"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
helpText("ITV"),

selectInput("metric", 
label = "Choose a variable to display",
choices = c("Households", "Population", "Adults15", "Adults18"), selected = "Population")

 ),
 mainPanel(

 plotOutput("map")
 )
 )
 ))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It would probably work better if you made your `switch` statement a reactive outside of the `renderPlot` like so:

```
 datafield <- reactive({switch(input$FieldMetric,
                              "Household"  = Plotdata$HHold_Est_2014,
                              "Population" = Plotdata$Pop_Est_2014,
                              "Adults 15+" = Plotdata$Adults15_Est_2014,
                              "Adults 18+" = Plotdata$Adults18_Est_2014
                     })
```

and then when making the plot use `fill=datafiled()` in your `geom_polygon`

Comment: Thanks: I had originally written it like that but didn't know about the reactive statement ... yes that new. That said - it still doesn't acknowledge datafield as an object: I get the error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : objected 'datafield' not found

Comment: did you write it as `datafield()` ? The `()` is required.

Comment: I tried it with and without. With brackets, it tells me the function cannot be found instead.

Comment: Is it something to do with datatypes? Is the reactive function, or switch function, not passing a list of integers back (i.e. my $Population data) ? Or changing the structure somehow?   Should it instead try and pass a string that I can reference in the fill statement?  I really just don't understand: I've copied code from the Shiny example (http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/) and by eye, it looks like for like.

Comment: Not sure what is up here, but you first try to just have `input$FieldMetric` rendered to the `ui` to make sure that  is working. Otherwise you may need to use `validat` in your renderplot example such as `renderplo({validate(need(input$FieldMetric, "Chose a variable"), ggplot()+....`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I've got a version that works but it's as ugly as. I'm more convinced than ever that I've just confused how to reference the input$metric returned from the UI.r in the SERVER.r and that for whatever reason I want a field header, but it's either returning the column of data (a series of integers) or some other object/data type.

I've bypassed it by using an if/else. Maybe someone will be able to improve the original solution in the future...

```
shinyServer(
function(input, output) {output$map <- renderPlot({

  if (input$metric=="Households"){
  ggplot() + coord_map() +
  geom_polygon(data = Plotdata, aes(y = PolyCoordsX, x = PolyCoordsY, group = Poly_Name, fill = Households), color = "black", size = 0.25)

  }else if (input$metric=="Population"){
    ggplot() + coord_map() +
      geom_polygon(data = Plotdata, aes(y = PolyCoordsX, x = PolyCoordsY, group = Poly_Name, fill = Population), color = "black", size = 0.25)

  }else if (input$metric=="Adults15"){
    ggplot() + coord_map() +
      geom_polygon(data = Plotdata, aes(y = PolyCoordsX, x = PolyCoordsY, group = Poly_Name, fill = Adults15), color = "black", size = 0.25)

  }else if (input$metric=="Adults18"){
    ggplot() + coord_map() +
      geom_polygon(data = Plotdata, aes(y = PolyCoordsX, x = PolyCoordsY, group = Poly_Name, fill = Adults18), color = "black", size = 0.25)

  }else return()
})
```

}
)